# micronaut rest response hangs regularly

Tags: netty, micronaut

I have some REST endpoints implemented in micronaut (service A). One of the endpoint calls another service (service X) using a `java.net.http.HttpRequest`. Service X may have a long response time, e.g. minutes.
Once this call is in progress, I am regularly calling service A (from curl) and every once in a while it just hangs.

[image: micronaut hangs]

I tested calling my service A with curl. For me it looks like that once service A is in the calling to service X, it's holding one of the `nioEventLoopGroup-1-x` threads waiting for the blocking operation to finish. Subsequent calls to service A endpoints will be handled by different `nioEventLoopGroup-1-#` threads in a round-robin fashion. But once the blocking `nioEventLoopGroup-1-x` would have the turn, the request just hangs. This behavior is deterministic, seeing from the logs which nio thread is handling the request, I see when the blocked thread has the turn, the call to service A just hangs. Then I make a new request to service A, which will respond perfectly. If given the netty thread pool size of 5 and 1 netty handler thread is blocked, then I will have every 5th request to service A hanging.

In my opinion Micronaut should never try to assign an http request handling to a thread that is blocked but apparently this is happening.

Does anyone have any suggestion how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out blocking operations within `io.micronaut.http.filter.HttpServerFilter` will block the Netty event loop, and will have the symptom I described above i.e. the blocked netty handler will become unresponsive.